# What makes Lucian Mid viable?

Tags: league-of-legends

It's a new thing since MSI: Lucian Mid.

But we are not talking about taking any ADC focused character in the mid lane, it seems to be only viable as Lucian.

So what makes Lucian Mid a viable choice over, let's say, caitlyn mid, or ashe mid, or jinx mid?

EDIT: I mean here what elements of his kit make it a pick that can go mid lane, or what are other ADCs missing that don't make them a regular midlane pick.

All that in a professionnal playing (LCS) stand point.

Comment: Eh, there are bits and parts that can be objectively examined. While it's not the *best* question, it's not *entirely* opinion-based.

Comment: @n_palum I see how you are thinking it. But I'm not asking why I see it in bronze, I'm asking why we see it on the professionnal scene. And that should be that there are x y attributes that make that character objectively viable in the mid lane.

Comment: Asking why we see it in SoloQ is completely opinion based, because well, I saw some friends try make braum jungle work. But looking at it from the LCS standpoint, it must, objectively, make some sense.

Comment: I can understand the objective side, where you can show the reasons why it was played, but at the end of the day, it's more or less someone's opinion on why it's good in mid lane.

Comment: Reminder - [game strategy questions are on topic.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I feel that the OP is asking from a strategical standpoint even if it may seem opinionated at first glance.

Comment: Added an edit, trying to push the question more on a objective side.

Comment: I don't like it and think it's still opinionated in its ways, but I'll retract my vote.

Comment: I really dislike questions like this because they're so heavily influenced by whatever the current meta is. Sure, Lucian mid might be viable *now*... but in 6 months, who knows? It's opinion based, but in a weird way that for some reason comes off as "objective". Questions about "the meta" are inherently opinion-based, because the meta itself is simply the majority opinion on what's currently strong.

Comment: Thing is, LoL is an always moving game... all questions about LoL should then be removed because I would bet no questions that are more than a year old about LoL still apply.

Comment: @MageXy This is a common concern with modern games that are as updated and changed as often as LoL. However I am of the opinion that the answerability of a question should not depend on unforeseeable changes in the future. What if Minecraft released an update that removed redstone? Should redstone questions not be asked on that that off chance?

Comment: @Yuuki "Unforeseeable" is the key word in that sentence. If Minecraft removed redstone, everyone would be surprised because it's been an important and core part of the game for so long. If Lucian mid stopped being played because it wasn't good anymore, not many would be surprised, because that change is expected to happen eventually, as it does with almost every champion. In fact, the only meta aspect of the game that's stayed consistent for a long time is the 1-top, 1-mid, 1-jungler, ADC-and-support-bot team composition, and even that was disrupted when Ziggs bot was meta a few months ago.

Comment: Also, if Minecraft did remove redstone, I think it would be a good idea to update related answers to say that, which only needs to be done once per answer. For a question like this, answers would need to be updated every time the meta shifted. That is wholly too much work for a single question. We're not a blog after all.

Comment: But that wraps around from being opinon an what we have here. We are not talking about how much things scale or things like that, I reworded the question to ask what, in his kit, made it viable in the middle; With that, if we don't get a full kit rework for Lucian (which would be pretty rare) this question still stands. It might not be meta anymore, but the kit elements that make it viable will be still there. Maybe Viable is not the right word then, but I have no idea what I would replace it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the ADCs, Lucian is perhaps the strongest duelist in the early game and has one of the best level 2 & 3 spikes as well as one of the best one item spikes. His dash makes him far more mobile than most ADCs and his E -> passive-empowered autoattack -> Q -> passive-empowered autoattack combo lays down a *lot* of burst.

Early game, particularly against mid champions that rely on scaling, Lucian is a powerhouse. He's meant to be a situational pick that can force trades against champions that rely on positioning and zoning.

As for what makes other ADCs less viable in the midlane, they're all missing a little something. Most ADCs aren't very mobile and the ones that are aren't mobile in the right way or are weak for other reasons. Draven can get a big speed boost from his W but it's just a simple speed boost not a dash and he's easily punished with zone control. Vayne has  a dash but her waveclear is atrocious. Ashe has strong waveclear with her W and use of Runaan's, but she has little to no mobility.
Tristana has mobility from her W and natural waveclear, but her early game damage just can't match up most mages.

Lucian has a bit of everything that makes up a good midlaner. Good mobility from his dash, strong burst and trade power from his combos, good waveclear with his Q, passive, and ult. So as far as ADC comparisons go, it's both where he's strong (very good early-game lane bully) and where he's not weak.

Comment: I would add that he has a strong ability to push with Q and R which added to his mobility allows him to roam easily and we all know pro players love to roam